# Make file readable only for program

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way in C++ to make file readable only for program without encrypting it? I want to create file which contains few lines of text that program reads, but the user must be unable to read it using simple prog. like "Notepad++".

Comment: Not using the **standard** C++ language.  File attributes and permissions are an operating system issue.  Look up API related to your operating system.  You may be able to use a Framework or portable library instead.

Comment: On Unix this is generally done by making the program setuid or setgid, and giving the file the same owner/group as the program. But writing setXid programs requires extra care.

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of pure C++, no.

As a matter of operating systems, generally speaking, no. If it is a file on disk, then in most OS's it is considered fair game. OS's often have ways to hide files, but users can bypass those. There are permission systems that can limit accesses to specific users. But a user with root/admin privileges can pretty much do whatever they want to the filesystem.

Now, some mobile OS's can [give your app some storage that can](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) [only be read by your app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), such that other apps aren't allowed to read/write as they see fit. But those are matters of OS-specific APIs.

And those schemes are not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Make your own binary format instead of usual text files. That is, you could jumble the bytes in a reversible way (I even have a very simple suggestion for that)

Comment: That's still encryption. It's just a really bad form of encryption.

Comment: Well, either encryption or permissions, though permissions can only act per-user, not per-program, in current operating systems (Android is a notable exception where each app has its own user ID on the system)

Comment: Encryption is not just used to secure files from say NSA or the like, it's is just used to represent something in another way. If you don't want users to see your files on their computer to modify them then your best bet is to store them in binary form and not plain text. With a good binary format you might even reach faster parsing of the data. That in my opinion is not a bad form of encryption.

Comment: @rlam12: The purpose of encryption is to encode information in a way that is difficult for someone other than authorized people to decode. The quality of a form of encryption is therefore defined by how effectively it does this. A binary file format is a terrible form of text encryption, due to its lack of effectiveness. That such a format might improve reading performance is irrelevant towards the question of whether it actually stops someone from reading it.

Comment: Depends. Often you want weak encryption. The casual user can't mess with the config settings, but if a problem develops, a software engineer can generate a new file without too much fuss.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not necessarily.  The question doesn't specify _how_ to prevent it from being read with simple programs, so simply shifting each byte up by one should meet the requirements (apart from the "without encrypting it" one), provided the simple programs in question don't provide a way to shift every byte down by one.